# DBaccess IOS framework. Nil in NSString fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dbaccess

I have a problem when trying to save object. Its properties are empty after saving.

My object:

```
@interface Route : DBObject
@property (strong) NSString* content;
@property bool hidden;
@end
```

Test code:

```
[DBAccess setDelegate:self];
[DBAccess openDatabaseNamed:@"test"];
Route * route = [Route new];
route.content = @"test content";
route.hidden = true;
[route commit];

DBResultSet * routes = [[Route query] fetch];
for (Route * r in routes) {
    NSLog(@"Route content %@, hidden %d", r.content, r.hidden);
}
```

`po route` after commit gives this:

```
| content            | UNKNOWN      | Nil value
| Id                 | NUMBER       | 1.000000                                            
| hidden             | NUMBER       | 0.000000
```

Log output:

```
Route content (null), hidden 0
```

Comment: tried setting the string property to copy instead of strong?

Comment: Thanks. It did not help unfortunately.

Comment: What happens if you declare `content` as `nonatomic` i.e. `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *content;` ?

Comment: Ahh, if you implement these properties as @dynamic, you will be in business.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue in the end?  We'd hate to think someone was having trouble!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBAccess requires properties that you would like to persist using the ORM to be implemented using @dynamic.

DBAccess injects it's own getters and setters into the class, but if you use @synthesize then Objective-c will traditionally create these for you or more recently it does this automatically if you do not specify anything at all.

Below is a section from the now almost finished, new website, with far clearer help and instruction:

> 4.) CREATE YOUR DATA OBJECTS
>
> DBAccess objects are normal classes with properties defined on
>   them, the ORM then inspects all these classes and mirrors their
>   structure in a SQLite database. If you add or remove columns then the
>   tables are updated to represent the current structure of the classes.
>
> Properties need to be implemented using @dynamic, this is to indicate
>   to the ORM that it will control the fetching and setting of these
>   values from the database.
>
> Any properties that are implemented using @synthesize will not be
>   persisted, but DBAccess will not interfere with them either.  This way
>   you can create large classes that are only partially utilised by the
>   ORM, but can remove the need for additional separate classes within
>   your application.